# Where do I get PCC (Pseudo City Code)

Tags: sabre

Where do I get Pseudo City Code for Air ticket booking? Does the GDS provides the PCC or IATA or any airline travel association provides that? We are developing booking application using Sabre GDS API's.

Answer (score 0):

Becoming a Sabre customer form:

https://www.sabresurveys.com/SE/?SID=SV_23Nc5mtmaUJOuJT

Comment: I am already a developer on the website but not sure where to get this pcc?

Answer (score 0):

Login in sabre developer portal . then click on edit profile
here you can configure the PCC.